# how do i run filename.py files as a argv[1] and settings.config files as a argv[2]

Tags: python-3.x

i am writing a python program for automatically uploaded files into google drive. need to run filename.py file with .CONFIG File input file in command prompt

ex: python3 filename.py .CONFIG File

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to use && oprator

```sh
python3 filename && .CONFIG File
```